# TextFitProperties usage

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

Blackberry Cascades 10.2

```
import bb.cascades 1.2

Page {
Container {
    layout: AbsoluteLayout {

    }
    Label {
        preferredWidth: 200
        preferredHeight: 150


        layoutProperties: AbsoluteLayoutProperties {
            positionX: 20
            positionY: 20
        }
        text: 'ThisIsALongTextInALabelThatHasMoreTextThanAPreviousLabel'
        textFit {
            mode: LabelTextFitMode.FitToBounds
            minFontSizeValue: 1
            maxFontSizeValue: 24
        }
    }
}
}
```

Text is truncated at the tail. Shouldn't it fit to the bounds of the label ?